# I need help writing a SARIMA model

Tags: arima

I need help writing a SARIMA model I have obtained mathematically. My model is

ARIMA(2,1,0)(0,1,0) period 12.

I understand what the different parts actually mean but get very lost trying to write out the mathematical model. I have tried to follow other examples but as the models differ it makes it hard to apply it to what I have.

Comment: There are dozens of similar questions on this site, so yours is most likely a duplicate of one or more of them. Consider looking them up; perhaps you will find that a relevant one has already been answered.